# Trabalhando Flyway com banco PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

Dá uma olhada no repositório.

[Repositório da Instituição AlgaWorks](https://github.com/algaworks/curso-angular-rest-spring-boot-api/tree/master/5.4%20Validando%20incosistencias/algamoney-api/src/main/resources/db/migration)

Esse projeto não é o meu, porém meu projeto está igualzinho a esse com uma única diferença, estou usando banco de dados PostgreSQL e os comando de SQL são esses que existem abaixo;

========================================================================

```
  CREATE TABLE categoria (
        codigo SERIAL,
        nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(codigo)
    );




INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Lazer');
INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Alimentação');
INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Supermercado');
INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Farmácia');
INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Outros');
```

===========================================================

```
CREATE TABLE pessoa (
    codigo SERIAL,
    nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    logradouro VARCHAR(30),
    numero VARCHAR(30),
    complemento VARCHAR(30),
    bairro VARCHAR(30),
    cep VARCHAR(30),
    cidade VARCHAR(30),
    estado VARCHAR(30),
    ativo BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(codigo)

) ;


INSERT INTO pessoa (nome, logradouro, numero, complemento, bairro, cep, cidade, estado, ativo) values ('João Silva', 'Rua do Abacaxi', '10', null, 'Brasil', '38.400-12', 'Uberlândia', 'MG', true);
INSERT INTO pessoa (nome, logradouro, numero, complemento, bairro, cep, cidade, estado, ativo) values ('Maria Rita', 'Rua do Sabiá', '110', 'Apto 101', 'Colina', '11.400-12', 'Ribeirão Preto', 'SP', true);
INSERT INTO pessoa (nome, logradouro, numero, complemento, bairro, cep, cidade, estado, ativo) values ('Pedro Santos', 'Rua da Bateria', '23', null, 'Morumbi', '54.212-12', 'Goiânia', 'GO', true);
INSERT INTO pessoa (nome, logradouro, numero, complemento, bairro, cep, cidade, estado, ativo) values ('Ricardo Pereira', 'Rua do Motorista', '123', 'Apto 302', 'Aparecida', '38.400-12', 'Salvador', 'BA', true);
INSERT INTO pessoa (nome, logradouro, numero, complemento, bairro, cep, cidade, estado, ativo) values ('Josué Mariano', 'Av Rio Branco', '321', null, 'Jardins', '56.400-12', 'Natal', 'RN', true);
INSERT INTO pessoa (nome, logradouro, numero, complemento, bairro, cep, cidade, estado, ativo) values ('Pedro Barbosa', 'Av Brasil', '100', null, 'Tubalina', '77.400-12', 'Porto Alegre', 'RS', true);
INSERT INTO pessoa (nome, logradouro, numero, complemento, bairro, cep, cidade, estado, ativo) values ('Henrique Medeiros', 'Rua do Sapo', '1120', 'Apto 201', 'Centro', '12.400-12', 'Rio de Janeiro', 'RJ', true);
INSERT INTO pessoa (nome, logradouro, numero, complemento, bairro, cep, cidade, estado, ativo) values ('Carlos Santana', 'Rua da Manga', '433', null, 'Centro', '31.400-12', 'Belo Horizonte', 'MG', true);
INSERT INTO pessoa (nome, logradouro, numero, complemento, bairro, cep, cidade, estado, ativo) values ('Leonardo Oliveira', 'Rua do Músico', '566', null, 'Segismundo Pereira', '38.400-00', 'Uberlândia', 'MG', true);
INSERT INTO pessoa (nome, logradouro, numero, complemento, bairro, cep, cidade, estado, ativo) values ('Isabela Martins', 'Rua da Terra', '1233', 'Apto 10', 'Vigilato', '99.400-12', 'Manaus', 'AM', true);
```

Se formos pega o projeto do AlgaWorks e executa-lo ele iria cria as tabelas e inserir os registros  como mostra um dos modelos do projeto, dá uma olhada abaixo;

```
CREATE TABLE categoria (
        codigo SERIAL,
        nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(codigo)
    );




INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Lazer');
INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Alimentação');
INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Supermercado');
INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Farmácia');
INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Outros');
```

**Qual é o meu problema?** Quando vou executar usando o banco de dados **PostgreSQL** ele somente cria as tabelas, ele não executa os **insert´s**, ele não grava os registros.

Gostaria de saber porque isso acontece!
Se for executado com o banco de dados MySQL ele executa os **insert´s**, porém com o banco de dados Postgre ele somente cria as tabelas e não inseri os registros.

========================================================================

mensagem do console:

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists categoria cascade
Hibernate: drop table if exists lancamento cascade
Hibernate: drop table if exists pessoa cascade
Hibernate: create table categoria (codigo  bigserial not null, nome varchar(20) not null, primary key (codigo))
Hibernate: create table lancamento (codigo  bigserial not null, data_pagamento date, data_vencimento date not null, descricao varchar(255) not null, observacao varchar(255), tipo varchar(255) not null, valor numeric(19, 2) not null, codigo_categoria int8 not null, codigo_pessoa int8 not null, primary key (codigo))
Hibernate: create table pessoa (codigo  bigserial not null, ativo boolean not null, bairro varchar(255), cep varchar(255), cidade varchar(255), complemento varchar(255), estado varchar(255), logradouro varchar(255), numero varchar(255), nome varchar(255) not null, primary key (codigo))
Hibernate: alter table lancamento add constraint FK3oktdfripre9vo4ocu87op55a foreign key (codigo_categoria) references categoria
Hibernate: alter table lancamento add constraint FK9pqx360616efx77k3w4j297yw foreign key (codigo_pessoa) references pessoa
[2m2017-11-17 09:55:58.547[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6652[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

OBS: Estou usando o Flyway para migração do banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade não cria a tabela.

Você não pode pegar o SQL de um banco de dados e usar em outro, cada um tem uma sintaxe diferente. Esquece o que está fazendo.

Este código mais ou menos convertido para o PostgreSQL ficaria assim:

```
CREATE TABLE categoria (
    codigo SERIAL,
    nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Lazer');
INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Alimentação');
INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Supermercado');
INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Farmácia');
INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Outros');
```

Veja [funcionando no **SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5865a/1) . Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/PostgreSQLSyntax.sql).

Não que seja uma conversão perfeita, mas só para funcionar.

Comment: sua sugestão não funcionou, conseguir criar as tabelas, mas não conseguir inserir os registros, o que será que você acha que deve está acontecendo?

Comment: Não faço a mínima ideia, eu mostrei que funciona.

Comment: Talvez eu não tenha sido claro, não estou usando utilizando o código SQL do Postgre direto no banco estou usando o flyway, você sabe mexer com Java?

Comment: claro que seu código vai de fato funcionar colocando o SQL direto no banco, você exclusivamente mostrou que funciona colocando o código direto no banco, mas você não mostrou ele funcionando em uma aplicação Java. Eu acredito que somente vai entender o que estou dizendo se você baixar a aplicação se você mesmo testar, se você baixar e conseguir funcionar no seu computador local, ai eu digo que posso ter feito algo errado.

Comment: Aí não é objetivo do site, Aqui ajudamos com problemas específicos que podem ser respondidos, não resolver o problema inteiro para a pessoa.

Comment: Eu sei que não é objetivo do site, mas você poderia fazer uma cortesia de me ajudar dessa forma, mas você tem toda liberdade para não fazer, porém em outras postagens existiram outros colaboradores do StackOverFlow me ajudaram dessa forma e nem por isso fiquei acomodado ou meu aprendizado foi deficiente.

Comment: Vou reformular minha pergunta, pois eu tenho certeza que vai aparecer outra pessoa para me ajuda.